# Change passwords every 90 days for ASP.Net to help PCIDSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pci-dss

I'm completing the PCIDSS assessment.

The requirements state passwords must be changes at least every 90 days, and be different from any of the previous 4 passwords.

I'm not certain whether this is for access to the server, or to the application I provide to users on the server.

If it's the latter - is there anyway of enforcing this in an ASP.Net 3.5/4 web application, and in an MVC4 web application?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: In case it helps clarify for anyone else, I received a response from TrustWave: The 8.5.X items would not apply to the users of the web application, but to accessing the server. So this is to do with security of the actual server, and not the users logging on to the web application. Hope this helps, Mark

Answer (score 1):

Is this for an in house application?  If so, consider integration with LDAP/Active Directory (assuming that's being used for your network passwords).  That can then take care of the password rules (i.e. tracking what's been used before, making sure passwords are sufficiently complex & different from previous ones & enforcing change frequency).  It also means your users won't have to remember/keep in synch multiple passwords, which they'll thank you for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Hi - no, it's a web application - so my customers of my website, logon to the web site, not through Windows.

Comment: For reference, we do this - LDAP server to enforce password policies of a internet-facing web app.

Answer (score 1):

For your first requirement, Asp.Net Membership has a property [MembershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastpasswordchangeddate.aspx) which you can then hook into your login like so:

```
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            MembershipUser theUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);
            if (theUser.LastPasswordChangedDate.Date.AddDays(90) < DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                // Inform user password expired + redirect user to change password screen
            }
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
        }
```

The second requirement (viz cannot be the same as the last 4 passwords) you will need to implement yourself. At a suggestion, create a new table `UserPasswordHistory` foreign keyed back to aspnet_User.UserId with a containing a password hash, which gets inserted every time the user changes his/her password. You can then compare the hash of the new password with the previous 4 and reject accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the passwords in another table, along with the date created.  That would be fairly straightforward

Comment: I'm using the default membership and role providers that come out of the box with ASP.Net.  I would hope I'm not the only asp.net developer trying to comply with PCI DSS, so I'm sure there must be a solution out there already.  Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score -1):

'I m not certain whether this is for access to the server, or to the application I provide to users on the server.

generally PCIDSS focus on server so .. this is for the access to the server.